# How to retrieve email on Linux?

Tags: command-line, email

My college signed me up with Office 365 and I'd like to be able to download the emails and either save to file or print to stdout within a script.

I've already managed to send email with scripts using Mutt, but I haven't found a way to download received email.

Please note that I'll want to download emails as part of something automatic, so a command line interface with ncurses is no good.  No human intervention.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, you can [use IMAP with Office365](https://support.office.com/en-nz/Article/Use-POP-or-IMAP-to-connect-to-Office-365-for-business-or-Microsoft-Exchange-accounts-44f951cc-2041-47ed-b674-506889ca9d8b) so you could use [OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/).

Comment: fetchmail also looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using mutt, you can configure the IMAP mailbox in mutt:

You would put in `~/.muttrc` a configuration like

```
set spoolfile="imaps://johndoe:p455w0rd@outlook.office365.com:993/INBOX"
```

see http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/UseIMAP

Alternatively, you could download the new mail to a [Maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) and process the emails locally (there will be a file per email).

Comment: How/where do I access the email through a script?

Comment: In other words, where are the emails going to be saved using this method?

Comment: @Dziugas if you are accessing an IMAP mailbox, emails are stored in the email server.